# answered: error when trying to paste a pdf into Word doc

Tags: pdf

## Problem:

On Win7 x64, copy PDF file; in Word 2010 v14.0.6123.5001, try to paste special as icon into docx document, get error:

> The program used to create this object is Package. That program is
> either not installed on your computer or it is not responding.  To
> edit this object, install Package or ensure that any dialog boxes in
> Package are closed.

---

Spent a bit of time searching on the error message and figuring this out; documenting it in case someone else gets the same error.

Answer (score 2):

### Fix:

Do not paste special.  Go to (ribbon) Insert, section Text, click button Object; tab Create New, Object Type = Adobe Acrobat Document, check Display as icon, Change Icon (if you want), click OK; file selection dialog will appear, choose file to be inserted.  Icon is inserted into doc; can be double-clicked to access PDF document.